# Enforce Jackson JSON field name when validating Javalin request

Tags: api, validation, jackson, javalin

I'm trying to validate my Javalin POST requests with a specific JSON field name. The field name *must* match the expected field name, and I'm not sure how I can do this.

The JSON field name I am expecting is "someIds", but the Jackson mapping and validation works even if the JSON field name is anything else (e.g. "notSomeIds").

How can I enforce that if the name doesn't match the validation stops?

```
if (ctx.body().isBlank() && !ctx.bodyValidator(ApiRequest.class).isValid()) {
        throw new BadRequestResponse("Invalid JSON body in request");
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `&&` or should it be `||`?

Comment: Minor observation: I think the preferred approach is to [let Javalin handle](https://javalin.io/documentation#validation) the `BadRequestResponse` on your behalf.